# How to setup a Role based authentication API using Node.js and Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

## Node.JS API using [sequelize](/questions/tagged/sequelize) as an [orm](/questions/tagged/orm)

---

Currently I am working on an [api](/questions/tagged/api) in [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js). I am looking for a proper way to integrate *role based authentication*. I've got a react Web App hosted on Heroku.com which is meant for our clients that buy our product. (reservation management system).

Besides the web app we also have an iOS and Android app which are for the customers of each client.

*The API login should work as following:*

- An user which is a Customer should not be able to login to the web app.
- An user which is a Employee should not be able to login to Mobile App.

MySQL database design:

---

[image: MySql database design picture]

Explanation Database Design:

---

- A user can either be an Employee or a Customer not both.
- Each Employee belongs to a group. (think of marketing, sales etc)
- Each Group has specific permissions. (e.g sales can view Average revenue)
- Same principle

> Important note: Future model will contain an extra table that will contain company specific groups.

**Question**

- How would I implement this using [sequelize](/questions/tagged/sequelize) & [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)?
- How would I check for the role/account type? (Customer || Employee)
- Should I have predefined groups in the database? (like defaults such as CEO)

Comment: You will need to write a middleware to check for a user's group and see if they have permission to do whatever they want to do. 

Sequelize will get you the logged user (and if you want to it's role and groups). Then it will be up to you do the checking to see if they are allowed or not.

Comment: @yBrodsky Thank you for your reply. Okey so I've got the middelware up and running for checking the User's group. Currently the problem is setting this up with Sequelize. How set up Users > Customers > Groups > Groups Permission > Permissions for example in a registration HTTP call?

Comment: well, you do that in your middleware. Once you know the user, it's only a matter of finding all the other data (groups, permissions, etc) and see if they are trying to access something they shouldnt.

Comment: Are you available for a chat on Discord/Skype or whatsoever? I would like to explain it in more detail.

Comment: No, I am at work. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @yBrodsky the part when registering a user. How do I get a user inside Customer or Employee database depending on the destination he is registering from. (web app or mobile app). And most importantly how to do that in Code. Should I first create a user, then store it’s ID in Customer or Employee, and lastly append him to a group? Or what is the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Well, if you have two sources of registration that do different things you will most likely have two different endpoints (ie `/register/web`, `/register/app`). And ye, you can create the user and once you have it's ID create the other relationships.

Comment: @yBrodsky Thank you! If you'll post this in a formatted answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: @yBrodsky btw: so that means I'll will end up with a duplication of every route? (login, register, send verification code etc?)

Comment: well, if you are telling they do completely different things....

Comment: @yBrodsky one is meant for companies, the other for customers of these companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as following:

> **How would I implement this using sequelize & node.js?**
>
> You'll first need to create a User entity in the database before you can wire up the relations with Employee. I've done this by doing it like this:

#### Create a user following by creating an Employee

---

```
models.User.create({
    first_name: body.firstName,
    last_name: body.lastName,
    email: body.email,
    password: body.password
  })
  .then((user) => {
    return models.Employee.create({ user_id: user.id, group_id: 1 })
  })
  .then((employee) => {

    if(!employee) {
      return utils.createError(400, 'Could not create account');
    }

     return response.status(200).send(employee);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    response.status(400).send(error);
  });
```

> **How would I check for the role/account type? (Customer || Employee)**
>
> I've done this by separating Front-end (native apps) and web apps routes in:
>
> - /api/web/register
> - /api/app/register

> **Should I have predefined groups in the database?**
>
> The answer would be yes. I've added a default group of CEO in the database in order to register the first user. Currently the model is undergoing heaps of changes, and soon the model will be a bit different.